# Eclipse and OpenGL setup on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having some trouble configuring eclipse correctly with OpenGL. I followed several tutorials online, but none seemed to solve the problem. What I have done is created a new project, and on right-click: properties->C/C++ build->Settings->Cross G++ Linker. Here I added the libraries 'glut' and 'GLU'. But whatever code I try to run, the compiler seems completely unaware of OpenGL completely. I also tried adding 'opengl' to the libraries, but this didn't help either. I have a working OpenGL/glut/GLU installation on my laptop, as I was previously using a text editor with the terminal to compile the code.

Answer (score 1):

You must install the OpenGL development files in Ubuntu first. Package name is `libgl1-mesa-dev`. And while you're at it, you might want to install some other convenience libraries as well. This should cover your immediate OpenGL development needs.

```
sudo apt-get install \
   libgl1-mesa-dev \
   libglu1-mesa-dev \
   libgles1-mesa-dev \
   libgles2-mesa-dev \
   libglew-dev \
   freeglut3-dev \
   libglfw-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure glut is installed in your computer, you can use the following command to do it

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```